# Finding derivative from (modified) Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am given a function $$f(x) = \frac{x^{1521}}{x^2+7x+6}$$

I found the Maclaurin series to be $$x^{1521}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac15\left(-1\right)^n - \frac{1}{30}\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)^n\right)x^n\right)$$

How do I find $f^{2011}(0)$? The $x^{1521}$ term is bugging me; I'm pretty sure it affects the Maclaurin series but I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: You can pull the factor $x^{1521}$ into the series, $$x^k\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n+k} = \sum_{m=k}^\infty a_{m-k}x^m.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x) = \frac{x^{1521}}{x^2+7x+6}=x^{1521}\frac{1}{1+x}\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{6}}$$
Using geometric series you get
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{6}x^{1521}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-x)^i\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{x}{6}\right)^{k}=\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}(-1)^\ell\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}6^{-k-1}x^{\ell+1521}=$$$$=\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}(-1)^\ell\frac{1}{5}\left(1-\frac{1}{6^{\ell+1}}\right)x^{\ell+1521}$$
Now you know that
$$f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(j)}(0)}{j!}x^j$$
To obtain $f^{(2011)}(0)$ you just need to compare the $x^{2011}$ term of these series:
$$\frac{f^{(2011)}(0)}{2011!}=(-1)^{490}\frac{1}{5}\left(1-\frac{1}{6^{491}}\right)$$
Hence
$$f^{(2011)}(0)=\frac{2011!}{5}\left(1-\frac{1}{6^{491}}\right)\ .$$